# What exactly does a XMPP server do?

Tags: websocket, client-server, xmpp

Besides federation (talking to other XMPP server), what's the role of an XMPP server in the communication between two peers?

Wikipedia says that

> The XMPP network uses a client–server architecture; clients do not
> talk directly to one another.

In that case, they must talk through the server, so messages must go through the server, correct?

Does it role change if we're using XMPP over Websockets, BOSH, or bare TCP?

For instance if we use XMPP over Websockets, is there a Websocket between client1 and the server, and another Websocket between client2 and the server?

Answer (score 1):

An XMPP server provides basic messaging, presence, and XML routing features. This page lists Jabber/XMPP server software that you can use to run your own XMPP service, either over the Internet or on a local area network. Wikipedia is also right. According to wikipedia it means that it uses server client system. It is a system in which a computing system composed of two logical parts: a server, which provides information or services, and a client, which requests them. On a network, for example, users can access server resources from their personal computers using client software. Server client system is widely used for communication purpose and also in DBMS

Comment: I know what a server is. What I'm asking is what specifically does an XMPP server do?

Answer (score 0):

actually it is a communication protocol for message oriented middle ware ( lies between software and application ) based on xml (extensible markup language ) It enables the near-real-time exchange of structured yet extensible data between any two or more network entities.